# Loading a 64 bit address into a register

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, riscv

I need to have my RISC-V assembly write instructions on the fly - (this is Forth so users can extend the language).
When I was using a 32 bit ISA this was relatively simple, say I wanted to get an offset from the address I am currently writing at i’d do something like write out the op codes for:

```
 lui s8, [upper 20 bits of address]
 addi s8, s8, [offset]
```

This no longer works when I have 64 bit addresses and as I have to write out the actual op codes and not just use assembly tricks like

```
li s8, address
```

I am puzzled as to how to do it. What is the correct way?

Comment: Can you use PC-relative addressing to generate a *nearby* 64-bit address efficiently in 1 or 2 instructions?  (e.g. if the address differs by less than 20 or less than 32 bits).

Comment: is `address` symbolic or its an actual numerical constant btw?

Comment: Consider using `gp`/`x3` to point to your global variables, then add a smaller constant to that.  Otherwise build larger constants from smaller ones using shift, add, etc..

Comment: @PeterCordes: stupid trick: `jmp + 8; dq constant ; li [pc - 12]`

Comment: @Joshua: Yes, that's possible if you can't find free space outside a function or otherwise need your machine-code fragment to be fully self-contained, but it's obviously inefficient to put it when you have to jump over it in the first place, instead of just before the start of the function, which should be reachable with a PC-relative load.

Comment: The mechanism needs to be generic as lots of words could be defined and they may get further and further away - I did use shifting (and or’ing rather than adding) as answer below shows

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Essentially I solved this by loading the higher 32 bits of the number into the bottom 32 bits, then shifting left by 32 bits and loading the bottom 32 bits.

This is a typical piece of output assembly:

```
  0x0000003ff7dbd040:  li  s8,63                     #0x3f
  0x0000003ff7dbd044:  slli    s8,s8,0x20            #shift left 32 bits
  0x0000003ff7dbd048:  lui t0,0xf7dbd                #upper half load
  0x0000003ff7dbd04c:  ori t0,t0,0                   
  0x0000003ff7dbd050:  slli    t0,t0,0x20
  0x0000003ff7dbd054:  srli    t0,t0,0x20
  0x0000003ff7dbd058:  or  s8,s8,t0
```

Comment: such sequence might not be macro-fused by the CPU. Always use the sequence specified in the RISC-V spec if available. In this case consider loading from a constant pool https://godbolt.org/z/1br1Pfjr8. But the better solution might be just arrange the code and data so that the offset lies within 32 bits and then it can be operated on easily using `auipc`

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to RISC-V AL, but not new to AL. Over 40 years ago, I did AL on an IBM 360, then a Z80 chip, a 6502 chip, a Wang computer, Raspberry PI, etc.

I like the following:

```
.text

la t0, some_function_addr
ld t0, 0(t0)
jalr t0

some_function_addr:  .dword  some_function

.data
```

Let the linker put the external-to-file address into some_function_addr.

I am not aware of any downsides.